# How to copy formatted HTML from DOM?

Tags: html, dom

I want to diff the sources between a few html but there are html sources with thousands of lines, and one or two lines which should be thousands of lines long. (PHP echoed with no new lines)

The DOM explorers in browsers parse and format it very nicely but only allow the original source to be copied.

Is there a way to copy the parsed/nicely formated code?

Comment: The DOM Explorer is not your original markup, it is the resulting markup from the DOM (constructed from your original markup). It will differ in places from yours, most likely.

Comment: I don't mind if it differs in quotes/closing tags etc. All that matters to me is that all of the elements are present.

Comment: It can differ much more than that. It may duplicate elements, modify nesting, and more. All depending on your original markup, its compliance to standards, and the browser's interpretation of your intent.

Comment: Okay. Was hoping for an aid in debugging some spaghetti code based on the differences in outputs.

Comment: Well, it's not likely to differ *that* much that diffing them would be completely useless. Also, if the browser modifies the tag order it's a strong hint that the original HTML should be fixed. In any case you could copy-paste the output to a HTML beautifier (easily found with Google) instead of trying to use the browser's version.